# Office 365 forwarding email to gmail goes to spam because fails DMARC

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, office-365

With Office 365 set to forward emails to Google Apps (i.e. Gmail), the forwarded messages are going to spam because according to the Gmail interface, they have "a from address in example.com but has failed example.com's required tests for authentication."

Viewing the source of the message it says

```
 dmarc=fail (p=REJECT dis=NONE) header.from=example.com
```

Is there some way to cause this not to happen?